# iOS - Run background process while app is in suspended state

Tags: ios, background-process, uilocalnotification, multitasking

I have an application which takes characters from a web page and compares them to a `UILabel` in the application. What I want to do is enable the app to continue to do this even when the user has placed the app in a suspended state. All I have found online and in the documentation is the way to schedule a `UILocalNotification` while still in the active state. In the documentation, it states that you can declare certain permissions in the `info.plist`. I looked at the categories, but my application cannot really fit any of those.
Is there a way for me to continue comparing the two strings and scheduling a notification while in the background?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS doesn't really support multi-tasking in the manner you require. (i.e.: You can't simply carry on processing data in the background unless you're a very specific kind of app such as a VOIP service, etc.) otherwise you're likely to end up being terminated.

However, one possible solution would be to carry our this monitoring on a separate system (e.g.: a web server that your app interacts with) rather than within the app itself. You'd therefore:

1. Communicate the required string/web page to your web service
2. Carry out the processing on the web server.
3. Send a push notification to your app if the string was found on the page in question.

Comment: So basically, you're saying that the only way that I will be able to accomplish this will be if I use Apple's Push notifications instead of the local ones? (I saw this in the documentation)

Comment: @Jeeter If you want to keep scanning the web page (rather than simply finishing an active scan, in which case you'll *probably* be OK) then this should be a better approach.